# Error in adding a suffix in a list of identifiers

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed

this is a recurrent topic but still not duplicate since I tried all the solutions and none worked for me.

I am trying to add the suffix "_1" to a list of identifiers imported from a txt file. The goal is to add this into a loop in a function.

GSE72343.txt:

```
SRR2182285
SRR2182286
SRR2182287
SRR2182288
SRR2182289
```

and I want to retrieve this:

```
SRR2182285_1
SRR2182286_1
SRR2182287_1
SRR2182288_1
SRR2182289_1
```

I've tried a couple of suggestions in other threads [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91493/rename-files-in-the-local-folder-adding-a-prefix-or-suffix) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434611/add-prefix-and-suffix-to-every-line-in-a-txt-file) but I am getting wrong outputs like showed below:

```
for i in $(cat GSE72343.txt); do echo "$i" "$i_1"; done
RR2182285
RR2182286
RR2182287
RR2182288
RR2182289

sed 's/$/ _1/' GSE72343.txt 
 _12182285
 _12182286
 _12182287
 _12182288
 _12182289



awk '{ print $0, "_1" }' GSE72343.txt
 _12182285
 _12182286
 _12182287
 _12182288
 _12182289
```

Any advices?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your for bash for loop, you need to use `{}` around your variable.
`for i in $(cat  GSE72343.txt); do echo "$i" "${i}_1"; done`

The way you have it currently, it is trying to reference the variable i_1, when really you want to reference the variable i and tack on _1 to the end of it. Using curly brackets in quotes allows you to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Your issue here is that your file has Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`). That's why your commands fail. If you fix the file, they should work as expected. If you have `dos2unix`, you can do:

```
dos2unix GSE72343.txt
```

But if not, you can also do it with `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' GSE72343.txt
```

After that your commands will work (with minor changes). And, as a proof of concept:

```
$ printf 'SRR2182285\r\nSRR2182286\r\n' > GSE72343.txt

$ cat GSE72343.txt
SRR2182285
SRR2182286

$ for i in $(cat GSE72343.txt); do echo "$i" "${i}_1"; done
 RR2182285
 RR2182286

$ sed -i 's/\r$//' GSE72343.txt

$ for i in $(cat GSE72343.txt); do echo "$i" "${i}_1"; done
SRR2182285 SRR2182285_1
SRR2182286 SRR2182286_1
```

Finally, if you don't wan to modify your original file, you can use any of the approaches you have in your question but just stick a `| tr -d '\r'` at the end. For instance:

```
$ sed 's/$/_1/' GSE72343.txt | tr -d '\r'
SRR2182285_1
SRR2182286_1
SRR2182287_1
SRR2182288_1
SRR2182289_1
```

Comment: That last one would be simpler just matching ```\r``` in the sed substitution: `s/\r?$/_1/`.

Comment: @TobySpeight well yes, but then it wouldn't demonstrate the point that you can "just stick a | tr -d '\r' at the end".

Comment: Like a charm... Thanks a lot. I've saved the file using Sublime and voila! Good to know all the options too. Great lesson!

Comment: @DanielSilvaeSilva Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Using your code `awk '{ print $0, "_1" }' GSE72343.txt` but without the comma:

```
awk '{ print $0 "_1" }' file
SRR2182285_1
SRR2182286_1
SRR2182287_1
SRR2182288_1
SRR2182289_1
```

Comment: This would probably not work with a DOS formatted text file, which is what the user in the question has.